# greyscale and resizing images

Tags: python, image, image-resizing

whenever I run my code nothing happens, nothing new happens in my folders that I want to happen.

Here is code:

```
from PIL import Image

def greyScaleAndSize(filename, numImages): 

img = Image.open('N:/Fall 2021/DataScienceIntroToPython/Lab 11/lab 11 logos' + ".jpg")
imgGreyscale = img.convert('L')

for i in range(1, numImages):
    imgGreyscale = img.resize((i*0.5, i*0.5))
    new_logos = 'N:/Fall 2021/DataScienceIntroToPython/Lab 11/lab 11 logos' + '__grey__' + str(i*0.5)+ 'x' + str(i+0.5) + '.jpg'
    imgGreyscale.save(new_logos)
    
img.close()
```

what I'm trying to do is convert to greyscale and resize(half of the original size) about 9 images from one folder and save them to a n ew folder..
but when i run code it doesn't crash and it doesn't show the new images in any folder..

Comment: You may start with the following post: [Loading all images using imread from a given folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30230592/loading-all-images-using-imread-from-a-given-folder).

Answer (score 0):

```
from PIL import Image
import os 


dirname, scriptname = os.path.split(os.path.abspath(__file__))

def greyScaleAndSize(filename): 

    img = Image.open(dirname + '/'+filename + ".jpg")
    imgGreyscale = img.convert('L')
 

    imgGreyscale = imgGreyscale.resize((img.width//2, img.height//2))
    new_logos = dirname + '/'+filename +'__grey__' + str(img.width*0.5)+ 'x' + str(img.height+0.5) + '.jpg'
    imgGreyscale.save(new_logos)
    
    img.close()

greyScaleAndSize('Orianna')
```

This code is working fine. Lets say you have a photo called Orianna.jpg
I used '/' unix style please pay attention to that. You can call this for a list of photo names.