# Flask FileStorage, load image from folder path

Tags: python, flask

Refereed to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30230592/loading-all-images-using-imread-from-a-given-folder) I created flask API with POST image method to predict image with OpenCV, but I'm having trouble how to load and read image from image path folder.

My code is like this

```
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = 'uploads/'
app.config['ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS'] = set(['png', 'jpg', 'jpeg'])

def allowed_file(filename):
    return '.' in filename and filename.rsplit('.', 1)[1] in app.config['ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS']
def load_images_from_folder(folder):
    images = []
    for filename in os.listdir(folder):
        img = cv2.imread(os.path.join(folder,filename))
        if img is not None:
            images.append(img)
    return images

@app.route('/predict', methods=['POST'])
def predict():
    file = request.files['file']
    if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
        filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
        file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
        image_np = load_images_from_folder(str(file))
```

That code gives this error

```
File "E:\cvob\app.py", line 87, in load_images_from_folder
    for filename in os.listdir(folder):
OSError: [WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: "<FileStorage: 'real-testing2.jpeg' ('image/jpeg')>"
```

What is the correct code? because I just learned to make this API

Comment: flask doesn't just give you paths. it gives you a `FileStorage` object. you need to use it appropriately. simply converting to `str()` apparently doesn't work. -- further, you pass a path to a file (or FileStorage) but then treat it like it's a folder? what's the idea there? files aren't folders